# convert string union to string enum in typescrpit

Tags: typescript

I want to convert string union to string enum,
but I don't know how. .

```
type strUnion = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';
```

convert to

```
enum str {
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b',
    c = 'c',
    d = 'd'
}
```

Do you know how?

Comment: What is the problem with that enum?

Comment: There's no way to take a type and emit an enum made from it, since types only exist in the type system and are erased when compiled to JS, while enums do get emitted.  You could take the type `strUnion` and make a *type* that matches `str` (e.g., `const s: {[K in strUnion]: K} = str;`), but nothing gets "converted".  Does this address your question or do you want something else?

Comment: What I want to do is enumerate variables defined as members by string concatenation.
This is quite correct, but when I tried it, it didn't work.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-enumerate
   
`make a type that matches str (e.g., const s: {[K in strUnion]: K} = str;),`
   
I need to define it twice, but it's type safe, so I think this is best if there is no other way.